# Git fatal ambiguous argument 'HEAD' both revision and file name use -- to separate paths from revision like git [....]--[...]

Tags: git

- My git version is 1.8.0 mysysgit0.
- Remote repo on -linux server.
- Local repo - Windows 7.

When I try to commit my local changes it says fatal error below:

```
fatal ambiguous argument 'HEAD' both revision and file name use -- to separate paths from revision like  git [....]--[...]
```

Could any one suggest what is the problem? What is the fix?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should quote the _exact command_ that is giving you the error. Without that it is not possible to provide concrete answer.

Comment: Console dumps could indeed be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a file named HEAD (perhaps with different casing?)

Answer (score 7):

You must have file in your repository called `HEAD`, and this is confusing `git` because `HEAD` is also customary name for currently active branch.

You can use double-dash to remove ambiguity, like this:

```
git log -- HEAD
```

This will show history about file named `HEAD`.

It is probably wise to avoid having files with these special names to avoid these issues.

Comment: Mvp,thanks for your answers,

tried "git log -- HEAD",But still i face the same issues,

Comment: Sorry, but you should provide more info if you want to be helped on this. Please show output of following commands (you can filter it for anonymity, but don't overdo it): `git branch`, `dir` (I am interested in presence of files named `head` or `HEAD` in current directory), and finally, how do you actually commit it? Error messages are also important - do not omit anything!

Comment: Tried "git branch" says "master"
FYI :: commit using git commit -a -m "test"-Works in git bash

but i couldn't able to commit by tortoisegit clients,,

When i try to commit using tortoiseit clients it says

Git fatal ambiguous argument 'HEAD' both revision and file name use -- to separate paths from revision like git [....]--[...]

No files showed in staging area..

Please let me know,if you need more info

Comment: `git commit -a -m "test"` will NOT work for new files unless you have `git add newfile.txt` first. In general, avoid using `git commit -a` - it is too risky. Instead, `git add changed-or-new`, and then `git commit -m "msg"`

Comment: i already done initial commit in my linux server,then i cloned the remote repo into local,Issue with my local repo..any fixes

Comment: tried googling,but no luck

Comment: All,I installed a bare repo with in the working directory,So that cause this.Once i delete the bare repo files(Head,index)..it works fine.

Thanks for your all comments

Comment: Ah, that error message was really confusing then. But you should have noticed that your directory contents was looking really strange. Still, it was good idea to give status update: +1 for your question.